# How would I convert an image to base64 in reactJS

Tags: javascript, base64

I have this function where I call a function and have a local file as the parameter to convert it to base64.

```
export const fileToBase64 = (filename, filepath) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    var file = new File([filename], filepath);
    var reader = new FileReader();
    // Read file content on file loaded event
    reader.onload = function(event) {
      resolve(event.target.result);
    };

    // Convert data to base64
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  });
}
```

Importing the function

```
  fileToBase64("shield.png", "./form").then(result => {
      console.log(result);
      console.log("here");
    });
```

gives me an output as

> data:application/octet-stream;base64,c2hpZWxkLnBuZw==
> here

I want base64 information, but noticing the file the application/octet-stream is wrong? I entered an image so shouldn't it be

> data:image/pgn;base64,c2hpZWxkLnBuZw==

https://medium.com/@simmibadhan/converting-file-to-base64-on-javascript-client-side-b2dfdfed75f6

Comment: What problem do you face with the above function, it seems like a right way to use and gives you the correct output too

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I edited the question above. I noticed that this `application/octet-stream` was incorrect should be `image/pgn`

Answer (score 0):

try this I think this should helpfull

```
let buff = new Buffer(result, 'base64');
let text = buff.toString('ascii');
console.log(text)
```

Comment: I added this to the code, but got this as the response `u+Zje F-
 !K^7k--f&m+k6VFBgfp`

Comment: When you are going to access docx and doc file then it should be data:application/octet-stream only but in case of image it will give data:image/pgn

Answer (score 0):

You must pass `type` option to `new File()`

```js
const file = new File(['file_name'], file_path, {
  type:'image/png'
})
```